# Appending text to a Window eventually stops adding text (Win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I am trying to append text into a child window. After a lot of text is written, nothing else is appended. I have tried catching errors and walking through the debugger when text stops being appended, but nothing is out of the ordinary - the debugger walks through the code and no text will be added, along with no errors showing.

Here is my appending function:

```cpp
void AppendText(HWND hEditWnd, std::string Text) {
    int idx = GetWindowTextLength(hEditWnd);
    SetLastError(NOERROR);
    SendMessage(hEditWnd, WM_SETFOCUS, (WPARAM)hEditWnd, 0);
    SendMessage(hEditWnd, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM) idx, (LPARAM) idx);
    SendMessage(hEditWnd, EM_REPLACESEL, WPARAM(TRUE), (LPARAM) ((LPSTR) Text.c_str()));
    ULONG dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    if (dwErrorCode != NOERROR)
    {
        printf("fail with %u error\n", dwErrorCode);
    }
}
```

Here is some sample code to try it out. In order to delay the function calls, I put a for loop for the program to crunch on. After ~30 seconds, text will stop being appended to the window.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <windowsx.h>

#define ID_GO 1
#define ID_GO_ONCE 2

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";
HWND hOut;

void AppendText(HWND hEditWnd, std::string Text) {
    int idx = GetWindowTextLength(hEditWnd);
    SetLastError(NOERROR);
    SendMessage(hEditWnd, WM_SETFOCUS, (WPARAM)hEditWnd, 0);
    SendMessage(hEditWnd, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM) idx, (LPARAM) idx);
    SendMessage(hEditWnd, EM_REPLACESEL, WPARAM(TRUE), (LPARAM) ((LPSTR) Text.c_str()));
    ULONG dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    if (dwErrorCode != NOERROR)
    {
        printf("fail with %u error\n", dwErrorCode);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HMENU hMenu, hSubMenu;

            hMenu = CreateMenu();

            hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_GO_ONCE, "&Go Once");
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_GO, "&Go");
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&Output");
            SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);

        }
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case ID_GO_ONCE:
                    AppendText(hOut, "-----HELLO-----\r\n");
                    AppendText(hOut, "-----TEST-----\r\n");
                    break;
                case ID_GO:
                    while(1) {
                        AppendText(hOut, "-----HELLO-----\r\n");
                        for(int q = 0; q < 7000000; q++);
                        AppendText(hOut, "-----TEST-----\r\n");
                        for(int q = 0; q < 7000000; q++);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
                   MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            g_szClassName,
            "Test GUI",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 680, 402,
            NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
                   MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hOut = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"",  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE |
                                        ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 0, 0, 680 - 20, 340, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Is there a limit on how much text can be displayed on a window?

Comment: Try a richedit instead

Comment: Try [EM_SETLIMITTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-setlimittext). The default limit is 32,767 chars.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you for that information. EM_SETLIMITTEXT is the cause - I called `SendMessage(hEditWnd, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, (WPARAM) 30, 0);` and only one set prints out. Is there any way to enter unlimited characters (or reset the message length sent)?

Comment: You don't actually do proper error checking. But if you want to work with huge amounts of text you are using the wrong control.

Comment: If all you want is a list of messages, you could try using a `ListBox` instead.

Comment: "Is there any way to enter unlimited characters" clearly not. You should delete older messages at some point. Navigating a list of millions of lines is impossible for a human.

Comment: @Anders Thanks. The easiest method for me is to clear the whole thing with `SendMessage(hOut, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)((LPSTR)""));`. It works fine from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CEdit control maximum length? (in characters it can display)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180853/cedit-control-maximum-length-in-characters-it-can-display)

Comment: ^^ Dupe is tagged MFC, but answers mention `EM_SETLIMITTEXT`, so it still applies.